# show all data from parent and child table

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have two simple one to many relationship tables of medicines and bills. as it happens, many medicines are bought by a single bill.
Now I have a page to show all the bills in each row of a table. Also, I want to be able to view all the sold medicines related to each bill by clicking on the respective bill and the medicines will show up below the row using JQuery.

This is my view code to depict all the bills in a table:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($bills as $bill)
       <tr role="row" class="odd">
          <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold">{{$bill->id}}</td>
          <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold">{{$bill->customername}}</td>
          <td class="v-align-middle">{{$bill->paid}}</td>
          <td class="v-align-middle">{{$bill->remainders}}</td>
          <td class="v-align-middle">{{$bill->total}}</td>
          <td class="v-align-middle">{{$bill->created_at}}</td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

and my controller code is:

```
public function index()
{
    $bill = Billpc::all();
    return view('bills')->with('bills', $bill);
}
```

Can anyone help me with how to show all the sold medicines related to the respective bill?

Comment: apply where method to get only sold item ?

Comment: Dear C2486, I want to show all the data from two tables at the same time. First I will show the data from the bills and then by clicking on each row, I want to see a list of medicines related to that data from Medicines Table.

Comment: but you have not joint any medicine relation here `Billpc::all();` ?

Comment: that is what I am stuck with. I don't know what to do and how to do.

Comment: Please check the doc, and try yourself first, otherwise I am always ready to help you. : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: have you tried calling `medicines` on the bill or whatever you defined the relationship as? Please check laravel docs first https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: My answer is not there in the document. Or maybe I am lazy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add relationships in your model

**Bill model**

```
public function medicines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Submission');
}
```

**Medicine model**:

```
public function bill()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AssignSubmission');
}
```

then change your code in your controller. use `with` to get the medicines in your bill

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $bill = Billpc::with('medicines')->get();

    return view('bills')->with('bills', $bill);
}
```